# Cannot iterate associative array keys in PKGBUILD

Tags: bash, shell, package, zsh, pkgbuild

I am working with a PKGBUILD file for the AUR. I have a lot of colors that need to be replaced in different files in the `$pkgsrc` directory and I wanted to use an associative array.

```sh
declare -A _BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#242424']='#1C1C1C'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#333333']='#292929'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#999999']='#787878'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#555555']='#4C4C4C'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#373737']='#2E2E2E'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#434343']='#383838'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#3E3E3E']='#333333'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#383838']='#2E2E2E'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#313131']='#262626'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#101010']='#101010'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#3B3B3B']='#303030'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#2A2A2A']='#1F1F1F'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#656565']='#575757'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#767676']='#5E5E5E'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#868686']='#787878'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#636363']='#595959'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#696969']='#5E5E5E'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#707070']='#666666'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#767676']='#6B6B6B'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#C1C1C1']='#B8B8B8'
_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS['#C6C6C6']='#BDBDBD'
```

That seems like a fairly clean solution, otherwise I would have many variables and that is less than ideal. Now, I iterate over these with the syntax found in other SO posts:

```sh
_blackish_replace() (
    shopt -s globstar

    echo "${!_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS[@]}"
    echo "${_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS[@]}"

    for file in "$1"/**/*.scss; do
        echo "Replacing colors in file: $file"
        for color in "${!_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS[@]}"; do
            echo "$color"
            sed -i "s;$color;${_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS["$color"]};gI" "$file"
        done
    done
)
```

It looks good to me, and when this is run in a standalone script, it does indeed replace the correct matches in the correct files.

However, when using it from `makepkg`, it fails silently, hence the four `echo` calls exhibited.

The first two output newlines. This leads me to believe they are undefined?

The iteration has proved to be working for the glob expansion, however `echo "$color"` is never reached; the loop iterates nothing.

I thought maybe `makepkg` was using the system shell, which in that case, running the code directly from my user shell `zsh` fails with `event not found: _BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS` or something alike (off the top of my head).

I asked in the Arch Linux Discord server if `makepkg` uses the locally available `bash`, and was assured it does. I am very confused.

Comment: What is the content of `$1`? And is `nullglob` enabled?

Comment: @AndreasLouv `$1` is `"$srcdir/$pkgbase-blackish"`, but that doesn't really matter as it correctly `echo`s the filenames. It is a considerably sized output, as expected. `nullglob` is off because I do not want it to start iterating files in `$1` in the event of a bad glob, I want it to instead attempt to iterate over the glob itself to force an error.

Comment: It seems like `makepkg` is a shell script, you might be able to run it with `bash -x /path/to/makepkg` to trace the execution.

Comment: @AndreasLouv As far as I can tell from the output of the trace, there is simply no reference to the execution of the inner loop at all. Every iteration stops at `echo "Replacing colors in file: $file"`. I ran it with `+x` and piped the result to a file. It is 230k lines so I may have missed something, or not known where to look.

Comment: I guess that you should be able to find your call to `_blackish_replace` and then follow it from there. I know it's overwhelming. Alternative then you can enable it in your script yourself, possible disable it when your script ends: `set -x` and `set +x`

Comment: @AndreasLouv I already looked at that. First instance of it running is at L53564: 
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/spikespaz/540efb9f3196009f68eae58778050801/raw

Comment: By declaring your function `_blackish_replace() (` with parenthesis instead of curly braces like this `_blackish_replace() {` you have it run in a new shell/subshell. Possibly you associative array is not populated before the sub-shell function is called. And because you populate your array using multiple statements instead of  assigning within a single-statement, the array gets populated gradually. Possibly not fully populated when your function is called and runs in the background (parallel while the array is not fully complete). Check you code before dismissing my answer.

Comment: @LéaGris Thanks! Here are the results after some experiments, after reading your posit. **1)** The `()` is intentional because I would like to keep anything that doesn't need global scope within itself. **2)** After replacing them with `{}`, there is no observed difference. **3)** After moving the AA `declare` and assignment (now one command) into `_blackish_replace`, with either type of parenthesis, it works! However, this raises more questions. **A)** I am using a bunch of other variables defined in the root of the script, they all work fine inside other subshells. Why is `declare` special?

Comment: @LéaGris **B)** If `makepkg` sources the bash script to get at the function `build()` (this is where `_blackish_replace` is called), why is the `declare`d AA not visible to the body of the function? Is the script not parsed and interpreted linearly from byte-0 to EOF? Why would it matter if the AA is made of multiple separate assignments? **C)** Is there another command/keyword I can use that will emulate the behavior of other globals and allow an associative array, so that I can keep all of the configuration constants at the top of the file for any passers-by to hack up?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a good idea to turn your array into a sed script before iterating the files:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A _BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS=(
  ['#242424']='#1C1C1C'
  ['#333333']='#292929'
  ['#999999']='#787878'
  ['#555555']='#4C4C4C'
  ['#373737']='#2E2E2E'
  ['#434343']='#383838'
  ['#3E3E3E']='#333333'
  ['#383838']='#2E2E2E'
  ['#313131']='#262626'
  ['#101010']='#101010'
  ['#3B3B3B']='#303030'
  ['#2A2A2A']='#1F1F1F'
  ['#656565']='#575757'
  ['#767676']='#5E5E5E'
  ['#868686']='#787878'
  ['#636363']='#595959'
  ['#696969']='#5E5E5E'
  ['#707070']='#666666'
  ['#767676']='#6B6B6B'
  ['#C1C1C1']='#B8B8B8'
  ['#C6C6C6']='#BDBDBD'
)

sed_script=
for k in "${!_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS[@]}"; do
  v="${_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS[$k]}"
  sed_script+="s/$k/$v/g;"
done

shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in "$1"/**/*.scss; do
  sed -i.bak -e "$sed_script" "$file"
done
```

Now in a more practical one-liner POSIX-shell friendly call:

```sh
find ./ -type f -name '*.scss' -exec sed -i.bak -e 's/#242424/#1C1C1C/g;s/#696969/#5E5E5E/g;s/#555555/#4C4C4C/g;s/#767676/#6B6B6B/g;s/#868686/#787878/g;s/#383838/#2E2E2E/g;s/#636363/#595959/g;s/#101010/#101010/g;s/#373737/#2E2E2E/g;s/#C6C6C6/#BDBDBD/g;s/#313131/#262626/g;s/#333333/#292929/g;s/#C1C1C1/#B8B8B8/g;s/#707070/#666666/g;s/#434343/#383838/g;s/#3E3E3E/#333333/g;s/#3B3B3B/#303030/g;s/#999999/#787878/g;s/#656565/#575757/g;s/#2A2A2A/#1F1F1F/g;' {} \;
```

To clarify the point of all the above:
As you are unsure about the shell brand running your `makepkg`, it is a safe route to choose the most portable shell code by sticking to POSIX-shell grammar, common tools and options.

Instead of choosing a quite over-engineered associative array here. The replacement instructions for `sed` can be layed-out as clearly as your associative array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# A plain string of sed replacement instructions
# is as compact and more portable than an associative array.
# It also saves from looping over each entry.

_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS='
s/#242424/#1C1C1C/g;
s/#696969/#5E5E5E/g;
s/#555555/#4C4C4C/g;
s/#767676/#6B6B6B/g;
s/#868686/#787878/g;
s/#383838/#2E2E2E/g;
s/#636363/#595959/g;
s/#101010/#101010/g;
s/#373737/#2E2E2E/g;
s/#C6C6C6/#BDBDBD/g;
s/#313131/#262626/g;
s/#333333/#292929/g;
s/#C1C1C1/#B8B8B8/g;
s/#707070/#666666/g;
s/#434343/#383838/g;
s/#3E3E3E/#333333/g;
s/#3B3B3B/#303030/g;
s/#999999/#787878/g;
s/#656565/#575757/g;
s/#2A2A2A/#1F1F1F/g;
'

_blackish_replace() {
  # Instead of iterating a bash specific globstar,
  # find -exec can replace it while sticking to the most
  # genuine POSIX-shell grammar.
  # find and sed tools are used with their most common options
  # avoiding gnu-specific extensions.
  find "$1" -type f -name '*.scss' -exec \
    sed -i.bak -e "$_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS" {} \;
}
```

Comment: I have incorporated this, and if I `echo "$script"` it simply prints a newline. This is not an answer. While it does help reduce the iterations, it does not solve the problem initially posed, as the question pertains to the expansion of `${!_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS[@]}` and `${_BLACKISH_REPLACEMENTS[$color]}` to `null` values.

Comment: As an aside that one-liner is ridiculous. Unless the editor hard-wraps text, that is going to be a very long, very painful process of horizontal scrolling in order to change the values, not to mention it is hard to distinguish each replacement from its source. Prone to mistakes, if I ever have to edit that. And I will.

Comment: @JacobBirkett the use of an associative array is overkill and not needed. My point is to demonstrate that any straight sed script will be as good if not better. Sed script can be read from a file if one wants to put a replacement per line it is perfectly good. As poster having issues with undetermined shell brand in his environment running the script. the suggested fall-back to plain POSIX-shell grammar is wholly relevant.

Comment: Something that is valid syntax is not working, I am troubleshooting, not talking about alternatives. Alternatives are okay to suggest when the question is likely an X/Y problem, but this is not, this is a question about associative arrays. In an environment that should be guaranteed(*) to use `bash`, as `makepkg` is a `bash` script (indicated by the shebang within) I should not be advised against using the features provided by the language which are at my disposal. The associative array feature is one of convenience, it provides an opportunity for clarity that I should like to make use of.

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to find the root cause of this expansion issue, as it appears to be. I'd rather know for the future, to learn from this phenomena, so that I can be prepared for the quirks of `bash` and similar shell languages. Using another, rather disorganized and less maintainable approach, just to avoid the problem to begin with has never and will never be a valid solution by my judgement. It's like "cleaning your room" and shoving everything under the bed.